# Oracle SQL update CTE table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation where I want to update a table in which there is a same ID but different column value!

What I want to achieve is, for the same ID, **if there is a value** of "TRUE" set both of the records as "TRUE".

In my case, I would want record with ID '3'  with a status NULL to be updated to TRUE and record with ID '4' with a status 'FALSE' to be updated to TRUE

```
ID    STATUS    AGE    MDI
__________________________
1    TRUE    18    89
1    TRUE    18    89
3    TRUE    18    89
3    NULL    19    99
4    TRUE    19    88
4    FALSE    18    88
5    TRUE     18    67
6    FALSE    18    77
```

This query below obtains the rows with the same ID but different value in STATUS:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl A LEFT JOIN tbl B ON A.ID= B.ID WHERE A.STATUS <> B.STATUS
```

I have already tried using CTE's since it's easier for me to do an approach like this:

```
UPDATE tbl A
SET STATUS = (
WITH TEMP AS(
SELECT * FROM tbl A LEFT JOIN tbl B ON A.ID= B.ID WHERE A.STATUS <> B.STATUS)
SELECT STATUS FROM TEMP WHERE A.ID = ID);
```

But I get an error like:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Plus I am not sure this is the correct approach, maybe a partition by window query would help but I am kinda stuck here.

Any leads would be much appreciated!

Comment: The WHERE clause condition makes the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. If you want true LEFT JOIN result, move the condition to the ON clause.

Comment: Should null be set to FALSE, if there is no TRUE? (For the same id.)

Comment: You only talked about id `3` and `4` but what happens in case of scenario like id `1` which might be the potential issue with the error at my first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only update the rows that need updating and correlating on the `ROWID` pseudo-column will be more efficient (than having to perform a self-join using `ID`):

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET status = 'TRUE'
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT status,
           MAX( status ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) AS max_status
    FROM   table_name
  )
  WHERE status IS NULL OR status <> max_status
  AND   max_status = 'TRUE'
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, STATUS, AGE, MDI ) AS
SELECT 1, 'TRUE',  18, 89 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'TRUE',  18, 89 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'TRUE',  18, 89 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL,    19, 99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'TRUE',  19, 88 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'FALSE', 18, 88 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'TRUE',  18, 67 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'FALSE', 18, 77 FROM DUAL;
```

Only updates 2 rows and updates the table to:

> ```
> ID | STATUS | AGE | MDI
> -: | :----- | --: | --:
>  1 | TRUE   |  18 |  89
>  1 | TRUE   |  18 |  89
>  3 | TRUE   |  18 |  89
>  3 | TRUE   |  19 |  99
>  4 | TRUE   |  19 |  88
>  4 | TRUE   |  18 |  88
>  5 | TRUE   |  18 |  67
>  6 | FALSE  |  18 |  77
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e37ce327927522f0ea86552769791266)*

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tbl A
SET STATUS = (select max(status) from tbl B WHERE A.ID = B.ID)

WHERE STATUS <> 'TRUE' OR STATUS IS NULL
```

The `WHERE` clause isn't really needed, but will keep the transaction size down.

Comment: This does not work as is, since Oracle SQL does not have a boolean data type (PL/SQL does but you can't use it in SQL) so it should be `'TRUE'` and you cannot compare using `IS` as that is only used for `IS NOT NULL`. If you change that to `WHERE STATUS <> 'TRUE'` then that still will not as the result of the comparison `NULL <> 'TRUE'` is not a truthy value so you'll need a separate comparison for `NULL`.

Comment: If you fix all of those issues then it will update every non-`'TRUE'` row in the table. The output would be correct but you may end up doing a lot of unnecessary work updating the rows where the maximum is not `'TRUE'` to an unchanged value.

Comment: On second thoughts, it will still be wrong for rows when you have a `'FALSE'` and a `NULL` pair as it will change the `NULL` value to `FALSE` when it should leave it unchanged. An example would be the last row in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=59ecd65446b79bc51b0955891b9b325c)

Comment: @MT0, I know. I asked OP about that case 41 minutes ago, but haven't got an answer.